# got this error in specific folders 'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

i just update my ionic and cordova version and i got weird issue.
in specific folders i got

> ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command

but when i try in other different folders i don't get this issue
[image]

I tried to reinstall the node, ionic and cordova and get the same problem.

npm version also shows different versions

> C:\Users\adirz>npm -v
>   4.0.5
>
> C:\Users\adirz>cd myapps
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps>npm -v
>   3.10.9

I run "where npm" command (edited)

> C:\Users\adirz>where npm C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm.cmd
>   C:\Users\adirz\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
>   C:\Users\adirz\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd C:\Users\adirz>cd myapps
>   C:\Users\adirz\myapps>where npm C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\npm.cmd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm.cmd
>   C:\Users\adirz\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
>   C:\Users\adirz\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps>

screenshot of environment variables 
[image]

C:\Users\adirz\npm
[image]

i open new folder and it looks like this

> C:\Users\adirz>npm -v
>   4.0.5
>
> C:\Users\adirz>ionic -v
>   2.1.18
>
> C:\Users\adirz>cd myapps
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps>cd haversami
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps\HaverSami>npm -v
>   3.10.9
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps\HaverSami>ionic -v 'ionic' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps\HaverSami>

Comment: Clearly ionic's folder is not on your PATH. And please learn how to copy/paste text from a command window. There was zero need to include an image here when a simple text post would have sufficed, and copy/pasting the text would have taken you about a tenth of the time and effort. Images should be used only when the problem cannot be demonstrated without them. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons to avoid images.

Comment: Next time i will know. I dont understand your answer,what is clearly ionic's folder?

Comment: *Clearly* means *it's clear*, and *ionic's folder* is *the folder where iconic  is located*, and what I wrote means *it's clear that the folder where ionic is installed is not on your path*.

Comment: what command did you use to install ionic?

Comment: npm install -g cordova ionic

Comment: @KenWhite it's never happen me before. before i update the version i could use ionic in any folder in my app.  when i updated the version, i reinstall ionic again and that's weird issue happened to me

Comment: @AdirZoari does npm work in those folders?

Comment: @SurajRao yes. but weird thing, it shows me different version in each folder. i edited the post you can see. in one folder it shows me npm -v 4.05 and other folder version 3.10.9

Comment: what is the path set for node in environment variables?

Comment: @SurajRao C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin

Comment: @SurajRao you prefer to see screen shot?

Comment: try 'where npm' command in both folders

Comment: delete the npm folder in adirz folder. You should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple versions of npm installed in different locations with one having packages of cordova and ionic.

Try

```
where npm
```

in the command line.

UPDATE:
your global npm installed in the system is C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.
your local one is in C:\Users\adirz\npm
Delete C:\Users\adirz\npm.
You may have to run npm install -g cordova ionic

Comment: delete the npm folder in adirz folder. You should be fine

Comment: which of them? i don't have folder called npm, node modules? i removed it before and install

Comment: C:\Users\adirz\npm

Comment: i removed, it wasn't folder, i add screen shot of the folder it removed

Comment: do where npm again in both locations

Comment: now install ionic and cordova globally.. it should work

Comment: after i install it worked but then i open another new folder then i wanted to install there my app and same issue. you can see in the post

Comment: So you have npm executables every folder?

Comment: the problem is it is taking the current folders npm over the system npm

Comment: wish i could do that, can you explain me?

Comment: Which current folders which of them and where is the system npm?

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm  is the system one...the one set in environmental variables

Comment: current folders meaning the path where you are running ionic start app

Comment: Ok which folders to take?

Comment: If i installed ionic globally why should i do that?

Comment: no...when you run npm in those folders,, it is running folder's npm instead of system

Comment: clean up the folders i guess.delete unwanted versions

Comment: From where ionic start app?

Comment: anywer..u have it globally.. delete unwanted npms

Comment: I did it and same issue, really stuck with that, i edited my post you can see